# /bin/sh: : No such file or directory Splunk MINT SDK

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, bash, shell

I am implementing BugSense using link http://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/MintIOSSDK/latest/DevGuide/Configureyourprojectforsymbolication

I have added the script for Configure server-side symbolication

SCRIPT=`/usr/bin/find "${SRCROOT}" -name splunkmint_postbuild_dsym_upload_script.sh | head -n 1`
/bin/sh "${SCRIPT}" "API_KEY" "API_TOKEN"

but when i am compiling my project xcode gives

/bin/sh: : No such file or directory

Comment: please properly format the question so it's clear what the actual script is (mark the code as `code`, keep line-breaks intact, don't insert additional  line-breaks...)

Comment: I got the answer my path of SplunkMint was not correct. SplunkMint.framework was only referenced but not present in bundle. In other linker flag - add "-ObjC" and "-all_load" flags after add framework in bundle.

Comment: if you found a solution, please add an *answer* to your (own) question and accept it. so the Q doesn't show up as unanswered (burning people's time)

Answer (score 2):

I got the solution.
I did't add SplunkMint.framework properly its was only referenced but not present in bundle.After adding referenced SplunkMint.framework in bundle I set the flag "-ObjC" and "-all_load" in other linker flag(In build setting) then compile.
Now its working fine.